# вывести две строки оператором where

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте такая проблема  не могу вывести данные в phpmyadmin суть проблемы не выводит две строки по ид
ошиок не выдает скрин приложил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.kl, users.Name, users.sebe, catalog_small, filename_small FROM users INNER JOIN images_ava ON users.id = images_ava.id WHERE users.id=53 ANA users.id=180
```

Comment: `WHERE users.id=53 ANA users.id=180` условие применяется к одной строке. id НЕ может быть одновременно равно 53 И 180. Может стоит написать OR что бы выдавали 53 ИЛИ 180 ...

Comment: да спасибо это то что нужно

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE users.id=53 ANA users.id=180
```

измени на

```
WHERE users.id=53 AND users.id=180
```

(слово `AND`)

Comment: Ответ выше дан OR ANA опечатка в скриншоте видно AND я ставил если ANA то ошибка была бы